# How can i generate two logging with different logging level using Log4j config file

Tags: java, file, logging, log4j

I want to generate logging in two logging file with different logging level using log4j config file.

For example `usual.log` with `INFO` level and `debug.log` with `DEBUG` level

Note: I already referred [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343577/log4j-is-it-required-to-have-multiple-logger-objects-for-creating-multiple-log?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322602/log4j-config-different-logs-to-different-files). I do not want to change existing java code so above links are not related to my question.

Comment: Am little confused, does debug.log file would contain DEBUG as well INFO log?

Comment: Yes, it should contains both DEBUG and INFO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want `debug.log` to include INFO as well as DEBUG.

```
log4j.appender.usual=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.usual.DatePattern=${roll.pattern.daily}
log4j.appender.usual.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.usual.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} [%t] %-5p %C{2} - %m%n
log4j.appender.usual.File=usual.log
log4j.appender.usual.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.debug=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debug.DatePattern=${roll.pattern.daily}
log4j.appender.debug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debug.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} [%t] %-5p %C{2} - %m%n
log4j.appender.debug.File=debug.log
log4j.appender.debug.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.logger.customlogger=DEBUG, usual, debug
```

The key is the `Threshold` filter for the appenders themselves. You can send all the logs to multiple appenders and have them filtered there.

The syntax above might be a touch off though, I'm more used to the XML configuration.