# log4j custom log file

Tags: java, log4j

I have created a *server.log* file through XML. Now I need to create a custom log file programmatically using [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). I have created this file, but it is empty and my log details are being stored in *server.log*. Below is my code snippet:

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(logdemo.class);

public logdemo() {
    try {
        logger.addAppender(new FileAppender(new PatternLayout(),"log/log1.log", false));
        logger.info("Printing INFO Statements");
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Printing ERROR Statements",e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you set the `FileAppender`'s  `append` argument to `true`?

Comment: Also, it would help if you show your log4j.properties and client code.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652032/how-can-i-create-2-separate-log-files-with-one-log4j-config-file

Comment: I have set FileAppender's append argument to true,but it's not working.

Comment: I'm trying to create custom file programmatically  without using log4j.properties file .