# Log4j multiple appender independently

Tags: java, log4j

I am using apache log4j.
I want to add 2 appenders. one for some purpose and 2nd for other.
The log content are not going to both appenders.
Let I have 2 appenders file1 and file2.
then Logger for file1 prints the record in file1.log. 
andLogger for file2 prints the record in file2.log.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652032/how-can-i-create-2-separate-log-files-with-one-log4j-config-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this snip code to log in 2 file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO

log4j.appender.debugLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLog.File=logs/debug.log
....

log4j.appender.reportsLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.reportsLog.File=logs/reports.log
....

log4j.category.debugLogger=TRACE, debugLog
log4j.additivity.debugLogger=false

log4j.category.reportsLogger=DEBUG, reportsLog
log4j.additivity.reportsLogger=false
```

And use this when you need to call log:

```
static final Logger debugLog = Logger.getLogger("debugLogger");
static final Logger resultLog = Logger.getLogger("reportsLogger");
```

Also if you already have log and dont want to change the log init. Log4j support you specify base on package or full quality pattern.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE

# Each package has different appender name     
log4j.logger.com.mycorp.project.first=DEBUG, FIRST
log4j.logger.com.mycorp.project.second=DEBUG, SECOND

log4j.appender.FIRST=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FIRST.File=./first.log
log4j.appender.FIRST.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.SECOND=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SECOND.File=./second.log
log4j.appender.SECOND.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Comment: is it possible that on same package/java file, info log goes to file1 and error log goes to file 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Create Two appenders like below:

```
public static final Logger loggerOne= LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.mylogger.loggerOne");
    public static final Logger loggerTwo= LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.mylogger.loggerTwo");
```

Then configure your Log4j.properties file like below:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file ,console

log4j.logger.com.mylogger.loggerOne=INFO,firstLog
log4j.appender.firstLog.File=C:/Imran/logs/firstLog.log
log4j.appender.firstLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.firstLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.firstLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.firstLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -%m%n

log4j.logger.com.mylogger.loggerTwo=INFO,secondLog
log4j.appender.secondLog.File=C:/Imran/logs/secondLog.log
log4j.appender.secondLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.secondLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.secondLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.secondLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -%m%n
```

Use loggerOne.info() and loggerTwo.info() in you code to print in the file firstLog.log and secondLog.log respectively.