# Is there a way to create a separate log file for each user ? (spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2, logback, spring-logback

I am working on a spring boot application, i want to create a separate logging file for each user of the application, is this possible ?

For example: user1.log, user2.log, user3.log, ....

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more precise about your problem and post the code of the solution you are building. We cannot do all the work for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with Kann's answer that the best approach is to filter after the fact, the answer to your question when using Log4j 2 would be to use the [RoutingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) or the [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) when using Logback. They both work similarly in that they will create new appenders for each unique item which can cause a problem with file handles. Log4j2's RoutingAppender provides for a PurgePolicy to handle that while Logback provides a timeToLive attribute. Logback uses a Discriminator class to choose how to determine how to match the log event to an Appender while Log4j 2 uses either a pattern that should contain a Lookup (Log4j 2's variable substitution mechanism) or a script to perform the matching.

If you are using java.util.logging you will have to write your own mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it will create as many log files as users. Imagine if your user base increases to 20K. Unless you have very strong need don't go for it.

Instead go for application level and user level loggings. To achieve this refer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652239